# Phonegap disable Camera configuration

Tags: android, ios, cordova, camera, phonegap

I'm working on an application for Android and IOS. In the application the user should be able to make some pictures, so I call the camera in Cordova with `navigator.camera.getPicture()`.
Is there any chance to disable all the configurations in the Camera Application which will be Called? So the User isn't able to activate flash, go to settings menue from camera, can't switch to front camera and so on. So he is only able to take a picture.

Unfortunately I think this isn't possible but maybe someone of you knows the gold Answer!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using the standard camera plugin provided by phonegap. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_camera.getPicture displays a full reference for the camera plug in and doesn't mention anywhere about having these capabilities.

One solution is that you could utilise this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera-preview#camera_Settings.FlashMode.

It would allow you to create your own camera interface where you wouldn't need to give the user access to any additional features other than taking a picture.